# How to import image into React from public folder through a json file

Tags: reactjs

As the title says I have multiple images and I want to keep them in a json where it stores the url and from there I want to get image data accordingly.

Here is my codesandbox, I am not sure why it is not showing any images after going through a bunch of answers here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-galois-2pn52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forget one level

> images

in JSON. Code of IMG in component should looks like this:

```
<img src={data.images.url} alt={data.images.name} />
```

Comment: That was quite silly of me I spent hours fixing my path while the problem was just in the structure of json

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `JSON` like

```
 <img src={`${data.images.url}`} alt={data.images.name} />
```

Please update your code. It will start showing the images.

Your `JSON` structure has `images` object in it which you are not consuming.